# Environment variable returns an empty string from a function in golang library

Tags: go, environment-variables, spotify

So currently I am trying to use the [spotify wrapper API](https://github.com/zmb3/spotify) for golang and am now facing issues with retrieving the environment for my SPOTIFY_ID and SPOTIFY_SECRET. I set my environment variables in a .env file and the .env file is stored in my project directory.

[image]

I am using the library [godotenv](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/joho/godotenv@v1.4.0) to load the env variables from my .env, and they are successfully getting outputted from my server binary. However, when I make a call to a function in the Spotify API module, I notice the environment returns an empty string, but it is set in my .env variables. I think it's because the module for the Spotify API module is in a go directory that is located outside of my project folder, so I suspect the scoping may be causing an issue but I am not entirely sure, because if I set the environment variables in terminal I have no issues. I was hoping I could set it in a .env file instead.

Comment: Check if the spotify api is getting those env variables in an init() function. If so, they are queries before main starts.

Comment: Will do so thanks for reaching back!

Comment: Note that environment variables are meant to be set in the environment, and not loaded from a .env file. Keeping environment variables in files defeats the purpose of environment variables (even if this is a common and accepted approach in JavaScriptLang and PHPLang). You might want to rethink the design.

Comment: I cloned the Spotify API project you are using. It does not read those env vars in an `init()` function as hypothesized by @BurakSerdar as one explanation for your problem. However, it is clear that depending on how you are instantiating (i.e., initializing) Spotify API objects it is certainly possible those functions are reading those env vars before you have loaded them by reading your ".env" file. That seems like the most likely explanation for your problem but you provided insufficient information for any definitive conclusion.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/how-to-read-environment-variables-of-a-process/70636#70636 for a good answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks Kurtis, I just got a chance to reply to this, but you were right. I changed the control flow in my codebase, so that I load the environment variables before the API methods try to call them.  Thanks again for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

A process's env is from its father process. Go process and the Spotify API module 's father process probably is terminal.

So if you want to set env through go and the Spotify API module can get it. Maybe, You can only start the Spotify API moduleby using go.

Comment: Wow I didn't know that that makes a lot sense, will have to dive deeper into this, thank you for the insight!

Comment: Sorry, but you don't know what you're talking about. Yes, env vars are initially set by (i.e., inherited from) the parent process. But a process is then free to modify its env vars -- including by reading a ".env" file. The question here is how, and when, the Spotify API reads the env vars it uses. As mentioned by Burak Serdar in a comment to the question it is possible that the Spotify API reads the env var in a `init()` function; which would mean it doesn't see any subsequent change due to reading a ".env" file.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/how-to-read-environment-variables-of-a-process/70636#70636 for the correct answer.